# Converting a String of a Date to a Date

Tags: java

I'm having troubles converting a String of a date entered by a user to an actual Date that can be sent to a database.

Ultimately the user enters a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD and it gets sent to the database. I'm trying this:

```
String date = "2015-03-02";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
```

this is all it outputs

```
Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 CST 2014
```

Comment: What does YYYY represent? What does DD represent? Why do you think so?

Comment: Maybe I'm formatting it wrong by I thought YYYY would represent 2015 and DD would be the day of 02

Comment: When you're not sure, you should check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Try with `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Thank you both. It was a dumb question I know, but it had me stumped thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format `String` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`; and something like

```
String date = "2015-03-02";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(parsedDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
2015-03-02
```